# Último domingo del mes pasado en vb

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Tengo este código donde saco el último día del mes, pero necesito saber que le falta para sacar el último domingo del mes pasado y cuantos días han transcurrido desde entonces:

```
    Sub Main(args As String())
        ''el ultimo domingo fue el 26/07

        **Dim dtmFecha As Date = Now
        Console.WriteLine("El resultado es: " & UltimoDiaDelMes(dtmFecha))
    End Sub
    Function UltimoDiaDelMes(ByVal dtmFecha As Date) As Date
        UltimoDiaDelMes = DateSerial(Year(dtmFecha), Month(dtmFecha) + 1, 0)
    End Function**
```

Comment: esta funcion, en diciembre, funciona? UltimoDiaDelMes = DateSerial(Year(dtmFecha), Month(dtmFecha) + 1, 0)

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo:

```
    Dim dtmFecha As Date = Date.Now
    Dim f1 As Date = DateSerial(Year(dtmFecha), Month(dtmFecha) + 1, 0)
    Dim ultimoDia As Integer = f1.Day
    'Genero una copia de la fecha para manipular sin afectar a la fecha original.
    Dim f2 As Date = New Date(f1.Ticks)
    Dim ultimoDomingo As Integer = 0
    'hago un for tomando el ultimo dia del mes hasta 1 buscando el ultimo domingo.
    For i As Integer = ultimoDia To 1 Step -1
         If (f2.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday) Then
            ultimoDomingo = f2.Day
            Exit For
        End If

        f2 = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, f2)

    Next
    Dim diferencia As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, f2, f1)
    Console.WriteLine("Ultimo día del mes es: " & ultimoDia)
    Console.WriteLine("Ultimo domingo del mes es el: " & ultimoDomingo)
    Console.WriteLine("La diferencia de dias entre ultimo día del mes y el ultimo domingo es de: " & diferencia)
```

Comment: muchas gracias, pero debo hacerlo sin for

Comment: Te he ampliado la respuesta para caso sin for aunque no lo habías mencionado en la pregunta. Cuida esos detalles para que el esfuerzo no sea en vano.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera.

```
Function UltimoDiaDelMes(ByVal dtmFecha As Date)
    Dim dateResult As Date, i as Integer
    ' Calcula el último día del mes
    dateResult = DateSerial(Year(dtmFecha), Month(dtmFecha) + 1, 0)
    ' Mostramos en pantalla
    Console.WriteLine("El último día del mes: " & dateResult)
    ' Recorremos el objeto Date hacia atrás para encontrar el
    ' último domingo
    For i = 1 To 30
        dateResult = dateResult.AddDays(-1)
        If (dateResult.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            exit for
        End if
    Next
    ' Mostramos el último domingo
    Console.WriteLine("El ultimo DOMINGO: " & dateResult)
    ' Aprovechamos el valor de i para indicar los días hasta final mes
    Console.WriteLine("Hay " & i & " días hasta final de mes")
End Function
```

Luego la llamada sería simplemente así ya que hemos aprovechado la propia función para mostrar en pantalla el resultado.

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    ''el ultimo domingo fue el 26/07

    Dim dtmFecha As Date = Today
    UltimoDiaDelMes(dtmFecha)
End Sub
```

Si no puedes usar for, basta con el valor entero de la enumeración de los días de la semana.

```
Dim ultimoDia As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dateResult.DayOfWeek)
```

La sentencia de arriba devuelve 0 si es Domingo, 1 si es Lunes, 2 si es Martes... de forma que ese valor numérico nos indica cuanto días hay desde el último día del mes hasta el domingo anterior.
Si vale 0 el último día del mes coincide que es Domingo, por tanto hay cero días. Si el último día del mes es Lunes = 1; entonces desde el último domingo hay 1 día hasta final de mes...

Así pues conociendo ese dato la fecha concreta del último Domíngo del més la puedes obtener así:

```
dateResult = dateResult.AddDays(-ultimoDia)
```

Comment: Gracias!! el problema es que no debo usar for